# 'NMinimize' finds wrong answer

Tags: mathematical-optimization

[image]

```
A = 10;
a2 = 2.0;
h2 = 1.0;
b2 = 2.0; 
d2 = 1850;  
L2 = 0.05; 
σ2 = 500;
c2 = Which[0 < d2*T <= 50, 7.5, 50 < d2*T <= 200, 5.5,200 < d2*T <= 400,0.5, 400 < d2*T <= 500, 2.5, 500 < d2*T, 1,True, 1];

NMinimize[{A/T + d2*T*c2 +h2*((d2*T)/2 + k*σ2*√(T + L2)) 
    + b2/T*σ2*√(T + L2)*(PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], k] 
    - k*(1 - CDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], k])), 0 <= T <= 3, 0 <= k <= 4}, 
    {T, k}, 
    Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"]

(* {1023.18, {T -> 0.0292988, k -> 2.17944}} *)

NMinimize[{A/T + d2*T*c2 + h2*((d2*T)/2 + k*σ2*√(T + L2)) 
    + b2/T*σ2*√(T + L2)*(PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], k] 
    - k*(1 - CDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], k])), 0 <= T <= 3, 0 <= k <= 4}, 
    {T, k}]

(* {1241.94, {T -> 0.27027, k -> 1.10251}} *)
```

I've always known `NMinimize` to find optimal values. However, in this case, `NMinimize` found a non-optimal answer, so I drew a plot instead.

How can I handle this? Do I have to use `Method - > "DifferentialEvolution"`?

Comment: Perhaps have a read of the this tutorial http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ConstrainedOptimizationGlobalNumerical.html

Comment: Also to [quote this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/22365/13162) "**A principle in successfully optimizing functions is to make them as smooth and convex as possible.**"

Comment: It is well worth checking what is the default method `NMinimize` chooses. If not differential evolution, it is probably Nelder-Mead, which is not a good global optimizer (it is a direct search method, but it is really still limited to local minimization). Differential evolution, as you see, is quite powerful (at the expense of many function evaluations); probably the most powerful of all methods offered. But all of the methods provided by `NMinimize` are just heuristics; you have no guarantee of finding the true global minimum in general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I get good result with v10.2 0n my Mac

```
$Version
```

> "10.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (July 7, 2015)"

```
A = 10;
a2 = 2;
h2 = 1;
b2 = 2;
d2 = 1850;
L2 = 5/100;
\[Sigma]2 = 500;
c2 = Which[0 < d2*T <= 50, 15/2, 50 < d2*T <= 200, 11/2, 200 < d2*T <= 400, 
   1/2, 400 < d2*T <= 500, 5/2, 500 < d2*T, 1, True, 1];

f[k_, T_] = 
  A/T + d2*T*c2 + h2*((d2*T)/2 + k*\[Sigma]2*\[Sqrt](T + L2)) + 
   b2/T*\[Sigma]2*\[Sqrt](T + L2)*(PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], k] - 
      k*(1 - CDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], k]));
```

It seems unusual to me that the function mixes a `PDF` with a `CDF`.

```
sol = NMinimize[{f[k, T], 0 <= T <= 3, 0 <= k <= 4}, {T, k}, 
    Method -> #] & /@
  {"DifferentialEvolution", Automatic}
```

> {{696.079, {T -> 0.108108, k -> 1.60671}}, {711.419, {T -> 0.108108,
>   k -> 1.90547}}}

```
sol = MinimalBy[sol, First][[1, -1]];

Show[
 Plot3D[f[k, T], {T, 0, 0.5}, {k, 0, 4},
  ClippingStyle -> None,
  PlotPoints -> {201, 50},
  PlotStyle -> Opacity[.8]],
 Graphics3D[{
   Red, AbsolutePointSize[6],
   Point[{T, k, f[k, T]} /. sol]}]]
```

[image]